Как вставить значение переменной в таблицу PL/SQL
Пытаюсь вставить значение переменной в таблицу, но появляется ошибка ORA-00904 (ругается на переменную)
DECLARE
newPlaces NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
insert into table1(goodId, weight, cost, places)
select t.goodId, t.weight, t.cost, newPlaces from table1 t where t.goodId = 1;
END

Подскажите, как правильно вставить значение переменной в качестве значения поля новой строки

Добавьте алиас к таблице и полям. Видимо оракл пытается найти поле в таблице с именем переменной. Либо в таблице нет одного из перечисленных полей в insert'е

Добавление алиасов не помогло( если вместо переменной поставить число, то все работает

Добавьте в вопрос, как вы добавили алиас. Должно быть что то вида select t.goodId, t.weight, t.cost, newPlaces from table1 t where t.goodId = 1;
